# Loading ListView with JSON data using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to parse JSON data from this url http://inspirontrance.com/tpb.json. My code works without the AsyncTask but with the AsyncTask enabled, app crashes after loading for a certain number of times. Although my codes seems ok but somehow the app freezes during the async process.

Here is my code,

```
    public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://inspirontrance.com/tpb.json";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_UPLOADS = "uploads";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSONArray
    JSONArray uploads = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new MyAsyncTask().execute(url);
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UploadsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... params) {

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Uploads
                uploads = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UPLOADS);

                // looping through All Uploads
                for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = uploads.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    UploadsList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return UploadsList;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, result,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ID, TAG_DATE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.id, R.id.date });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u post crash report

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it. It's good to get into the habit of doing your pre/post work within your task.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UploadsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();        }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Uploads
            uploads = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UPLOADS);

            // looping through All Uploads
            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = uploads.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                UploadsList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return UploadsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, result,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ID, TAG_DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.id, R.id.date });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy I was wondering if you could explain how I would do this if I have an incrementing if statement that calls each string? I'd be willing to even pay you via paypal or whatever if you can help me. It's quite specific, not sure if I would be able to ask on SO.