# How to load dynamic contents to slider drawer in android?

Tags: android, slider, drawer

Hi I had created an android app which contains a slider drawer.I want to add dynamic contents to slider drawer(load image,text from server etc )when app runs .Is it possible?? please help me and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a demo on [github](https://github.com/penkzhou/CustomDrawerMenuDemo).In the demo,the [NavigationDrawerFragment](https://github.com/penkzhou/CustomDrawerMenuDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/penkzhou/customdrawermenudemo/app/NavigationDrawerFragment.java) file is like your slider drawer ,the main list in the drawer is come from this code spinnet :

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
```

So you could replace it with a data load function and load dynamic contents in the file.:

```
public void loadDynamicData(){
   //1. show a progress bar when the data is not ready.
   //2. use AsyncTask to load data in background.
   //3. when data is ready,replace the progress bar with data. 
}
```

If you also want to add an actionbar-pulltorefresh library, you can add [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) to the drawer.It's very easy. And if you want to load the image logo (such as user's avatar),you could use the [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).

Comment: I want to add add slider drawer layout to my project from the library project I created with 2 or 3 line code.is it possible??

Comment: You mean have written a slide drawer library project and you want to import the slide drawer class from the slide drawer library project?

Comment: ya exactly.I am struggling with last 1 month to solve this. so please help me if u have any idea about it. plz :)

Comment: I already created a library project.so now i want to add slider drawer  functions in library and then tell me how to call this function in another project from library??

Comment: Maybe you could get some idea from the [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Comment: is it possible to make custom view ??

Answer (score 0):

If you use ListView in slider drawer then you need to load data via asynctask and make a custom Listview.

So, What step you need to do.

> 1. Read Data via Asynctask.
> 2. Create Custom adapter by this Reading data.
> 3. Set this adapter in listvoew.

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872988/loading-listview-with-json-data-using-asynctask-in-android)

Comment: I want to add add slider drawer layout to my project from the library project I created with 2 or 3 line code.is it possible??